# Need to get value from xml file using perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I have the following xml file `strings.xml`. I need to get the value `1.0.0.44` from:

```
<string name="app_version">1.0.0.44</string>
```

How can I do that using XML::Simple?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <string name="drawer_item_text">Drawer Item</string>
  string name="drawer_image_desc">Icon for the Navigation drawer item</string>
  <string name="app_version">1.0.0.44</string>
 <string name="module_version_no">1.0.1.20</string>
```

I have not worked much on XML parsing using Perl? A pointer will be a great help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The [documentation for XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) is available, but you [probably don't want XML::Simple](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-3/).

Answer (score 1):

Using XML::LibXML;

```
use v5.16;
use XML::LibXML;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => *DATA{IO});
say $dom->findvalue('//string[@name="app_version"]');
__DATA__
<resources>
  <string name="drawer_item_text">Drawer Item</string>
  <string name="drawer_image_desc">Icon for the Navigation drawer item</string>
  <string name="app_version">1.0.0.44</string>
  <string name="module_version_no">1.0.1.20</string>
</resources>
```

Output `1.0.0.44`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parsefile('test.xml');
print $twig->findvalue('string[@name="app_version"]');
```

output is:

```
1.0.0.44
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `XML::Simple`:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces

I would sugggest [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) instead. (As an alternative to the `XML::LibXML` solution already posted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub process_string {
    my ( $twig, $string ) = @_;
    if ( $string->att('name') eq 'app_version' ) {
        print $string ->text, "\n";
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented',
    'twig_handlers' => { 'string' => \&process_string },

);

$twig->parse( \*DATA );


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <string name="drawer_item_text">Drawer Item</string>
  <string name="drawer_image_desc">Icon for the Navigation drawer item</string>
  <string name="app_version">1.0.0.44</string>
   <string name="module_version_no">1.0.1.20</string>
 </resources>
```